# Python - WinError 32 when deleting last .zip file

Tags: python, automation, python-zipfile

I am trying to export .zip files from the Downloads folder into a directory for my work. Some file names repeat so I have set it up to rename files to be different as to not overlap. After it exports, I want it to delete the .zip files in Downloads but the very last .zip file for some reason throws a "[WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: {full file path}" I would appreciate some input on this!

```
import os, shutil, time
import zipfile

def unzip(download_path, dir_path):
    num = 0
    bad_files = 0
    to_delete = []
    for filename in os.listdir(download_path):
        f = os.path.join(download_path, filename)
        if (filename == "desktop.ini"):
            pass
        elif filename.endswith(".zip"):
            i = 0
            z = zipfile.ZipFile(download_path + '\\' + filename)
            print(z.namelist()) 
            with zipfile.ZipFile(f, 'r') as zObject:
                zObject.extractall(path=dir_path)
                    
            split_file = z.namelist()[0].split('/')[i]
            print(split_file)
            
            time.sleep(1)
            try:
                os.rename(dir_path + '\\' + split_file, f'{dir_path}\\{filename[:6]}.zip_{split_file}')
            except:
                os.rename(dir_path + '\\' + split_file, f'{dir_path}\\error_duplicate_{split_file}')
                pass

            to_delete.append(f)
            i += 1
            print(f"File {num + 1}")

        elif filename.endswith(".crdownload"):
            print("error: " + filename)
            bad_files += 1
            print(f"File {num + 1}")
        else:
            shutil.move(f'{download_path}\\{filename}', f'{dir_path}\\{filename}')
            print(f"File {num + 1}")
        num += 1
        time.sleep(2)

        for file in to_delete:
            os.remove(file)

    print(f"Bad files: {bad_files}")
```

The program runs great and does exactly what I want up until the last file when it throws the error.
I have tried closing the .zip with `zObject.close()` but that does nothing, I am assuming because I am using the `with` clause. I have also tried a for loop

```
for _ in range(3):
         if not to_delete:
             break

         for file in to_delete.copy():
             try:
                 os.remove(file)
             except PermissionError:
                 pass
             else:
                 to_delete.remove(file)
```

with no luck...

Comment: Maybe the last file is still in the process of being downloaded, so it's in use by the download application.

Comment: Why are you using string concatenation to create paths when you obviously know how to use `os.path.join()`?

Comment: @Barmar, the files are all done downloading when this function starts. You make a great point about concatenation though... Don't know why I didn't think of that...

Comment: Which line in the script is getting the error? Please post the full traceback.

Comment: The loop that deletes the files should not be inside the `for filename in os.listdir(download_path):` loop. It should be after the loop is done.

Comment: @Barmar, the for loop was in the wrong place, I still get the same error. Here is the full error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\manuf\Desktop\Automate\unzip_files.py", line 63, in <module>
    unzip(return_download(), return_dir())
  File "C:\Users\manuf\Desktop\Automate\unzip_files.py", line 58, in unzip
    os.remove(file)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\manuf\\Downloads\\528147_00BB_P8147 Jaw DBTs.zip'

Comment: I don't know Windows well, but does it have a tool to find out what other process is using the file?

Comment: @Barmar, yes, the Resource Monitor but I cannot find anything in there.

Comment: The problem is you never closed `z`. I'm not sure why you even need that, since it's the same as `zObject`. If you want to see the name list use `print(zObject.namelist())`

Comment: If you really want another opening, use `with` like you did with `zObject`, so it will be closed automatically.

Comment: @Barmar, WOW! That was exactly it! I added z.close() and it fixed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem due to

```
z = zipfile.ZipFile(download_path + '\\' + filename)
```

This is never being closed. Each time through the loop you reuse the variable, so the garbage collector automatically closes the previous zip file. But the last one never gets closed.

Use

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(f) as z:
```

around the section of the code that uses `z` so it gets closed automatically.